# Native date input ignores CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

I have a problem with native inputs of type `date`. My case consists of a native form with multiple native inputs of different types (`text`, `number`, `date`, etc.) The application featuring the form has a sticky header which results in the following behaviour:

Whenever the form is submitted and the form validation encounters an invalid input for an input field, the form automatically scrolls so that the affected field shows up at the very top of the browser, while showing the validation error message. This field is obscured by the sticky header.

I solved this problem by using the `scroll-margin` CSS property for the input fields, which respects the height of the sticky header.

This works great for all input types, except for date input fields.

I was not able to find any official bug reports.
Has anyone else encountered this behaviour? If so, how could I fix this, without the use of JQuery?

```css
body {
  max-width: 500px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #1976D2;
}

input[type=text] {
  scroll-margin-top: 150px;
}

input[type=date] {
  scroll-margin-top: 150px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Fixed Header.
</header>

<form>
  <input type="text" required/>
  <br/>
  <input type="date" required/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Apply scroll-margin to an element wrapping these input fields instead?

Comment: @CBroe I tried wrapping the element in a `div` which I applied the scroll-margin to, however, this did not work either. The solution with scroll-margin works how intended for all other input fields in firefox and for all input fields, including the date type input field, in e.g. Chrome.

Comment: @CBroe Added a codepen example

Comment: Yeah, can reproduce the issue. Guess you'll have to file a bug report then, since applying it to a wrapper element indeed does not seem to help. _"This works great for all relevant browsers"_ - I'm seeing the exact same problem in a Chromium-based browser though ...?

Comment: @CBroe you are correct, it also does not work in Chromium-based browsers... I had a bug in my application which made me think otherwise. I edited the question. I was also experimenting with the `onInvalid` prop for inputs and calculated the scroll position and scrolled "manually". However, the native form validation overwrote the scroll position...

Comment: You could use a timeout to get around the native form validation overwriting. In any case, it's going to be challenging to work around it; I'd say you're probably better off either using a normal text field along with a datepicker component or informing users of the need to scroll for the date field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Who needs javascript when it can be done with a single line of CSS? Just add `html { scroll-padding-top: 70px; }` :)

```css
html {
  scroll-padding-top: 70px;
}

body {
  max-width: 500px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #1976D2;
}

input[type=submit] {
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Fixed Header.
</header>

<form>
  <input type="text" required/>
  <br/>
  <input type="date" required/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m4uxj321/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand your objective but from the demo I can see that you maybe have a long form with a lot of inputs and you want to scroll back to the input with an alert, you can accomplish that with `JavaScript` easily using

```
document.querySelector('#element').scrollIntoView();
```

you can make the scrolling animation smooth by adding

```
document.querySelector('#element').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

But I also think you want to use the browser's default validation, so this is how to detect the input that has an invalid value, and scroll to it.

```
const element = document.getElementById("element");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (element.validity.typeMismatch) {
    // scroll to the invalid input
    document.querySelector(element).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
   
    // Show a custom Error/Warning
    email.setCustomValidity("You need to fill this !!?!");
  } else {
    email.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```

if that's what you want, then I advice you to stay away from `CSS` and stick with `JavaScript`, you can also check the DOM Object `ValidityState` that is accessible through `element.validity`, it has all the browser's defalut validation info you need.
you can also read [Client-side form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) and [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

**EDIT:**
@ViktorG is right, `scrollIntoView()` would never get the job done without some complex trick, but we can still use the normal scroll and prevent the default browser behavior while making use of the browser's alerts using `reportValidity()`, sadly it's not possible to use `preventDefault()` just on the scroll and keeping the alert since it doesn't take parameters.

the snippet demo is working good enough but ofc you need to tweak it to fit your desired result.

```js
const el = e => document.querySelector(e),
    ela = e => document.querySelectorAll(e),
    btn = el('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let len = ela('form input').length - 1; // -1 is meant to stop before we reach the button, if you're using button then remove it

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (!el('form')[i].checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault();

            /*
             *   We're scrolling to the element position - the header height * 2, to always make the element visible.
             * */
            window.scroll({
                top: el('#input').offsetTop - (el('header').scrollHeight * 2),
                behavior: "smooth"
            });

            /*
             *   The Delay is meant to prevent reportValidity() from scrolling till the first scrolling fase is done.
             * */
            setTimeout(() => {
                el('form')[i].reportValidity(); // we manually trigger the browser's validation
            }, 800);

            break; // we break because we only show one alert at a time
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body {
            max-width: 500px;
            font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.4;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 4rem 1rem;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
        
        header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 1rem;
            background: #1976D2;
        }
        
        input[type=text] {
            scroll-margin-top: 150px;
        }
        
        input[type=date] {
            scroll-margin-top: 150px;
        }
        
        input[type=submit] {
            margin-top: 500px;
        }
```

```html
<header>
        Fixed Header.
      </header>
      
      <form>
        <input type="text" required/>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="sdsdsd" id="sdds" required/>
        <br>
        <input type="date" id="input" required/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" id="btn">
      </form>
```

Comment: NOTE: my answer is based of :invalid in general so you can even use it as an event, like: `input.addEventListener('invalid', callback)`, @ViktorG mentioned that the browser is scrolling and he doesn't want that, you can listen for the invalid event and use `event.preventDefault()` and then scroll to it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to implement your approach into the code example that I provided and it resulted in the same behaviour as described in the question. Could you provide a working code example?

Comment: Based on @hassan-aoutof answer I made a working demo although ScrollIntoView did not work with a margin top so I used a custom function to get the dimensions and scroll via window.scrollTo method. https://jsfiddle.net/2so36hyz/

Comment: @ViktorG, i added a working example, sadly it wasn't as small as i was hoping because i was forced to use `checkValidity` and `reportValidity`, and it had to be used in an array format.